# Calculating CSS values with jQuery and ems

Tags: jquery, css, font-size

I have to use a calculated value for a project. Best would be to use the CSS3 `calc`attribute. However, this is not supported by Android Webview native browser. Therefore, the easiest way I found was to use jQuery to handle this behavior:

```
$(element).css('width','100%').css('width','-=100px');
```

Problem is that this time, I need to use an em value instead of a px value:

```
$(element).css('width','100%').css('width','-=1em');
```

This will not work.

Would you have any (simple) solution to handle that problem?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to create a variable for the calculation.

```
var calc = 0;
```

Then use that var to output your new value.

```
calc = $(element).width() - 100;
```

Write this value to your console to make sure you're ok with the value.

```
console.log(calc);
```

Once you're alright with that you should be able to use it in setting the width in css

```
$(newElement).css({"width" , calc + "px"}); 
//Note: this syntax allows for multiple attributes to be applied to an element.
```

If you need further assistance then I've created a JSFiddle where you can ..fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/Fp7qp/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're best off doing the math without ems.  Unless you declare a font size on the element, 1em will equal 16px.